# Deploying Multiple Django projects on apache with wsgi

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost, wsgi

I am trying to give a Domain name and run multiple django projects on my apache

```
<VirtualHost first.site.com:80>
     ServerName first.site.com
     WSGIDaemonProcess first
     WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/project/first/first/wsgi.py process-group=first application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    <Directory /opt/project/first/first>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost second.site.com:80>
     ServerName second.site.com
     WSGIDaemonProcess second
     WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/project/second/second/wsgi.py process-group=second application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    <Directory /opt/project/second/second>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but, second website don't work.

```
 You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Virtual Host Settings from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4

Apache 2.2

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Apache 2.4

```
Require all granted
```

Comment: If you had the appropriate Apache compatibility module loaded, then the old way should still work. Without the compatibility module, is likely that Apache would have errored when being started as it wouldn't have known what the directives were.

Answer (score 0):

Are all directories from / down to the directory where the WSGI script files are readable to the Apache user? That is the main reason why you get this error.

Comment: chmod -R 777 /opt/project/second..and apache restart.. still have the same problem

Comment: Don't simply chmod 777. That exposes everything to writing and is bad practice.